# How to get Windows service username in Java?

Tags: java, windows

If I run a Java process as background service then `System.getProperty("user.name")` returns ever the hostname with an additional $ character.

Is there a solution to get the real user name of the process which I can see in the Windows task manager?

Comment: AFAIK, most services run under the [Local System Account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/services/localsystem-account). You can change that when you start the service.

Comment: A service can run under *any* user account. It's unclear what statistics made you propose that *"most services"* were to run under the local system account, @joh.

Comment: @IInspectable Just looking at the services control panel on my system - a fairly vanilla Win10 install. Most are "Local System" and a few are "Network Service" and that's it. I mentioned in my first comment that it can be any user. Guess I wasn't clear on that last point.

Comment: You can try `ProcessHandle.current().info().user().get()`, but I can’t promise it will return a different value.

Comment: @JohnnyMopp It does not help if service mostly run under the Local System Account. I have a problem with services which do it not.

Comment: @VGR Works, it give the user with domain prefix like "IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool". If you add it as answer then I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain the user who owns the current Java process using `ProcessHandle.current().info().user().get()`.  It should be the same information provided by the system’s task list.

The documentation for ProcessHandle is [here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessHandle.html).